# LINQ, select the latest entered children for an entity

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity as Plan with multiple sub-plans (children), each of which could be null. What I am looking for is an efficient way of retrieving all the latest entered children plans only for a particular patient.

```
public class Patient
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
}
public class Plan
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public virtual PlanDetail PlanChild1 { get; set; }
   public virtual ObservationCare PlanChild2 { get; set; }
}

public class PlanDetail
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }
   public virtual string Description { get; set; }
   //And other properties....
}

public class ObservationCare
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }
   public virtual string Description { get; set; }
   //And other properties....
}
```

So, for example, assume today is Friday and there are 5 plans for a patient (Id: 5) from Monday to Friday, and there was one `PlanDetail` per day and 1 `ObservationCare` for Thursday and one for Monday, I want to have an anonymous object which holds the latest entered `PlanDetail` (which in my example would be Friday) and `ObservationCare` (which in my example would be Thursday) and skip the rest.

In short I want an anonymous object to be return from the query which holds each child as one of its properties.

Comment: What is the significance of these days (Thursday and Friday) in your example?

Comment: nothing! That was just an example! Each day has its own plan and I want to retrieve the latest child plan of throughout the plans.

Comment: How many entities do you want to retrieve (_latest entered children_ is a broad description of a number), and in your example why are you interested in `PlanDetail` for Friday and `ObservationCare` for Thursday (what if you are retrieving only one plan)? 
And why do you have two identical classes?!

Comment: @mohamed-elshawaf I am expecting to get only one Child-plan (the latest entered). I am not interested in any particular day of the week. In my example I assumed today is Friday, therefore the latest Plandetail entered would be the Friday one and ObservationCare, Thu. Those classes are not identical, there are other properties in each that I did not list there for keeping it short

Comment: Hi Mohammed, has your problem been solved? did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var orderedPlans = plans.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id);
dynamic latestAggregatedPlan = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject(); //.NET +4.5
latestAggregatedPlan.Detail = plans.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PlanChild1 != null)?.PlanChild1;
latestAggregatedPlan.Observation = plans.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PlanChild2 != null)?.PlanChild2;
```

Hope it's what you are looking for!